# Java - adding and removing buttons during runtime

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

so I am new to Java Swing GUI's and I am creating a student management system. The idea is that when the program is launched there is a button for each module on the screen, clicking each button would take you to another window with information about the module. I want a feature to be able to add and remove modules, so my idea is that during run-time you are able to add a new button representing a new module or delete a button when you want to remove that module.

I have tried many different things but the problem I am running into most is that I can create the button just fine, but I can't add it to the frame.

```
public class GUI {
//  -=GLOBAL VARIABLES=-
    public int moduleCount = 0; //Setting the module count to 0, this will increase/decrease as modules are made/deleted. This variable allows the program to determine where to position each button
    
//  -=CREATING MODULE METHOD=-  
    public void addButton(String name, String text){
        //Calculates positioning of each button based on quantity of buttons
        moduleCount += 1;
        int x = 150 / moduleCount;
        int y = 100 / moduleCount; 
        
        JButton newButton = new JButton();
        newButton.setText(text);
        newButton.setBounds(x, y, 100, 40);
        newButton.setName(name);
    }

    public GUI () {
        
//      -=CREATING THE FRAME=-
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Student Management System"); //Creating a new frame
        frame.setSize(750, 500);//400 width and 500 height  
        frame.setLayout(null);//using no layout managers 
        frame.setVisible(true);//making the frame visible 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        
    }
}
```

If this is at all possible (even if I've gone in the complete wrong direction), any help would be greatly appreciated :)

EDIT: I understand I don't actually add the button to the frame, I have tried this. Everytime I use

```
frame.add(newButton);
```

or with casting GUI first, it just doesn't add it to the frame

Comment: Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. The problem with your code is you never add the button to the frame. Where do you actually build your application logic? Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html). It will show how to create a simple interface. You will need to modify the code to add your buttons.

Comment: I don't know if @camickr will agree with me on this, but I think you need to look into Card Layout (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) and use this layout manager to switch to the (card) panel that represents the correct view for the current module. I think this solution is better than adding and/or removing components from a view based on the same conditions. So basically, create the panels for the modules EXACTLY the way they are supposed to look like, and then let the layout manager "shuffle" your card panels based on the current module.

Comment: @hfontanez, yes I would agree. You need one panel to contain the buttons. Then when you click on a button you swap panels using the CardLayout.

Comment: Rather than 'adding buttons' I suggest using a `JList` and instead adding new functionality as entries in the list's model.

Answer (score 0):

```
frame.add(newButton);
frame.revalidate(); // not necessary with null layout, but please don't use null
frame.repaint();
```

That should fix it for you, but listen to the guys that commented on your question; **do not use null layouts** as it will cause it to not respond to resizes and make the code messy.

The reason you'd normally need revalidate is because a component has been added and therefore the layout needs to recalculate the positions of your components.

Repaint is needed for, as the name implies, telling the frame to repaint, although is usually not needed if only altering components (like calling `button.setText("new")`).

Also, small trick: if the element you just added only appears after resizing the frame, you forgot to revalidate and/or repaint.

Comment: This is also messy. You don't want to add and/or remove buttons. You want to have all your panels built and simply switch them when the current module changes.